# spring boot configuration class not load from sub module

Tags: spring-boot

I have multi modules projects :

```
myapi : com.project.api
mypersistence : com.project.persistence
mymodel
myweb
```

the api module has mypersistence as a dependency.
the configuration class i'm talking about is supposed to be detected from classpath which is not the case for a reason I ignore or miss

The configuration class PersistenceConfig is under `com.project.persistence.config` package in persistence module

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.todaysspecial.persistence.repositories"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.todaysspecial.model"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
}
```

ApiApplication class is under `com.project.api`

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I moved everything under `com.project`
but I'm not convinced since I want to use `com.project.api` package